# Azure function to access AWS Elastic Search with IP access rules

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, azure-functions

I am trying to access elastic search instance from azure functions app, after adding the IP address into AWS access policy functions app supposedly lives on I get the error as if it indeed wasn't added. I know for sure this approach works I have other IPs in white-listed yet one from Azure just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where did you get this IP from?

Comment: @Mikhail from the app properties in azure portal (and it matches when I hit the endpoint)

Comment: If the IP matches what Azure gives you, everything seems correct from Azure side, right? It sounds more like a configuration issue on the AWS side.

Comment: Alsp, note that Functions only support a fixed list of outgoing IPs when using an App Service Plan, and not when using Consumption.

Comment: Ah, I am using consumption plan though